# Store Google Auth credentials with Python

Tags: python, api, youtube

I grabbed the same code from the Google API documentation. The code I grabbed prompts a user to authorize that my application can use their account to then like a video. This is the code

```
import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FILE.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.videos().rate(
        id="eyRGEv3XAxk",
        rating="like"
    )
    request.execute()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code works with a valid "client secret file". But is there any way for me to save the credentials, so that I don't always have to prompt the user to authorize my application? Say I want to like another video in another part of my code, but I don't want to authorize again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the python pickle library to save and load the credentials object.